# What would you say it hurts when you laugh?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, writing

Let's say two people are talking, and one of them starts to laugh so hard he is in pain (nothing medical to worry about, just out of breath or something). What is he likely to say?

- Oh, my (blank) hurts!

How many options can you think of to fill in the blank and what are the most common?

Answer (score 1):

I think the most commonly used expression to describe a situation where you're laughing so hard that you start feeling pain in certain parts of your body (primarily in the abdominal area) would be the expression *my stomach hurts*:

> This is so funny that my stomach hurts.

Answer (score 1):

A related idiom is "[sidesplitting laughter"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sidesplitting), e.g. to laugh so hard it feels like your *sides* are going to *split open*.

Comment: Could you say...?
"HAHAHA, this is so funny my *side* hurts"
or...
"I can't take it anymore! My *side* hurts so bad!"
(in context, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

When laughing hysterically at someone’s humor, one can also say to them:

[You’re killing me!](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/you%27re+killing+me.html)

added to or followed by what @Cookie Monster has suggested.